# Woocommerce new product set ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a new simple product in Woocommerce programmatically:

```
            $product = new \WC_Product_Simple();
            $product->set_id($virtualProduct->id);
            $product->set_parent_id($virtualProduct->parent_id);
            $product->set_name($virtualProduct->name);
            $product->set_slug($virtualProduct->slug);
            $product->set_date_created($virtualProduct->date_created);
            $product->set_date_modified($virtualProduct->date_modified);
            $product->set_status($virtualProduct->status);
            $product->set_featured($virtualProduct->featured);
            $product->set_catalog_visibility($virtualProduct->catalog_visibility);
            $product->set_description(strip_tags($virtualProduct->description));
            $product->set_short_description(strip_tags($virtualProduct->short_description));
            $product->set_sku($virtualProduct->sku);
            $product->set_regular_price($virtualProduct->regular_price);
            $product->set_sale_price($virtualProduct->sale_price);
            $product->set_category_ids([148]);
            $product->save();
```

Whenever I specify the ID via `set_id` the product doesn't get added. Perhaps my approach is wrong. I want to keep the same ID as the origin `$virtualProduct` which is coming in from another Woocommerce website.

Answer (score 1):

If your website has its own products, orders, posts, pages then you are risking of having your ID number being already taken vs another Woocomerce website is sending to you.

I would suggest you to let Woocommerce set ID, and instead you can identify your products by SKU number, which you need to set unique anyway. And know which products come from your virtual woocommerce by having sku starting with "VIRTUAL-" just as an example.

If you absolutely need to capture ID you can set it as a meta data, then when you call virtual woocommerce back, you can call it by this ID that is stored in meta data rather than actual ID.

Comment: This is not a problem, as a matter of course, I check if the ID exists first, and this is also a fresh install.

Comment: I see, then maybe you can var_dump($virtualProduct); and see if $virtualProduct->id is actually there, maybe $product->set_id() receives null? Additionally, try to use capital-cased ID (i.e. $virtualProduct->ID) as that might also be an issue here and also gives you null if it's lowercase.